# I have a laravel website that is connected to phpmyadmin but now I want to connect android app to same database

Tags: php, android, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have created a website with laravel where the user can register ,post ,upload etc and it is all stored in phpmyadmin .Now I would like to create an app where the administrator can access all the data that is stored in phpmyadmin .I have not tried before connecting website and app to the same database before so this is new to me.At the moment when I try to insert data from (testing with POSTMAN before I create the app) Postman I get the message "Not Found" ,can you please tell me what I'm doing that is wrong .

connection.php  class

```
 <?php

    define('hostname','localhost');
    define('user','root');
    define('password','');
    define('databaseName','socialmedia_website');

    $connect = mysqli_connect(hostname,user,password,databaseName)

    ?>
```

InsertData.php class

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    require 'connection.php'
    createUser();

}

function createUser()
{

    global $connect;

     $name = $_POST["name"];

     $email = $_POST["email"];

     $password = $_POST["password"];


     $query = "Insert into user(name,email,password) values ('$name','email','password');";

     mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
     mysqli_close($connect);
}
```

[Here is a screenshot of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha8hh.jpg)

Comment: Handle requests in a or multiple controllers and define routes in api.php (if Laravel 5.3+)

Comment: I think you need API to communicate with that database

Comment: You're data is never stored in PhpMyAdmin, it is stored in a database, PhpMyAdmin is only a web based sql client. What you want is to insert your data into a database..

Comment: @ka_lin yes I'm using laravel 5.4

Comment: @Ian So the data saved in PhpmyAdmin where is saved then?What database is saved in,it has to be saved somewhere

Comment: @Rachel Yes it's saved in a database, PMA is only the client to connect to the database(s). You don't store data through PMA to insert it into a database.

Comment: @Ian your comment is contradicting yourself. "Your data is never stored in PhpMyAdmin, it is stored in a database" and "What you want is to insert your data into a database"...

Comment: Why you are using PHP code if you are using laravel. You can create API's in laravel too

Comment: @Rachel You have some mistakes in your php code: `$query = "Insert into user(name,email,password) values ('$name','email','password');";`. It's suppose to be `$email` and `$password` instead of `email` and `password`. You are also vulnerable to sql injection and you're not encrypting your password.

Comment: @Loko I'm just trying to get the basics done first then apply security when I have the basics finished

Comment: @Rachel You can make an API to communicate with your database. (Apparently you can also use the mysql jdbc driver)

Comment: @Loko How is that contradictory? Your confusing is that you think PhpMyAdmin is a database when it's not.

Comment: @Loko any links to API tutorial or guides would be really helpful if you could leave them here please

Comment: @Ian I am not confusing phpmyadmin with a database. Im not OP. Anyway, you say OP wants it stored in a database, yet you say OP's data is stored in a database right before you say that.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin is nothing more than a front end to a MySQL server.

In your laravel app, you will need to create URL API endpoints that your app can call. Make your DB call in your Laravel API controller, then return the data as JSON.

Comment: Is there a guide or article where I could follow this method ?

Comment: For Laravel? Probably. Look up laravel API controller example! In a controller, just call your db, get the results, then json_encode the array, header Content-Type as application/json, echo out your JSON string, then die();

Answer (score 0):

Direct connection is also possible with JDBC Driver *jtds 1.3.1.jar* or any latest. I Used it to connect my android app to SQL DataBase and performed CRUD operatios
Here's is the connectionString
`

```
public class ConnectionClass {
    String ip = "xxxxxxxx";
    String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "xxxx";
    String un = "xxxxx";
    String password = "xxxxx";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {

            Class.forName(classs);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                    + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERROR", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

`